Can I run create two expressions and two columns where the second column references the first in the same line?
I have a database as follows from the FRED API:
self.yielddiff_lf
shape: (9, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ statistic  ┆ Date                       ┆ 5y Rate  ┆ 1y Rate  ┆ Rate Spread │
│ ---        ┆ ---                        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---         │
│ str        ┆ str                        ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64         │
╞════════════╪════════════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│ count      ┆ 82                         ┆ 82.0     ┆ 82.0     ┆ 82.0        │
│ mean       ┆ 2023-03-02 08:29:16.097000 ┆ 3.737073 ┆ 4.740244 ┆ -1.003171   │
│ std        ┆ null                       ┆ 0.267561 ┆ 0.220112 ┆ 0.145185    │
│ min        ┆ 2023-01-03                 ┆ 3.36     ┆ 4.19     ┆ -1.29       │
│ 25%        ┆ 2023-02-01                 ┆ 3.54     ┆ 4.64     ┆ -1.12       │
│ 50%        ┆ 2023-03-03                 ┆ 3.66     ┆ 4.71     ┆ -1.03       │
│ 75%        ┆ 2023-03-31                 ┆ 3.93     ┆ 4.88     ┆ -0.92       │
│ max        ┆ 2023-04-28                 ┆ 4.34     ┆ 5.25     ┆ -0.6        │
└────────────┴────────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘

I am trying to create a column that is the Rate Spread (5y / Numerator) minus 1y (denominator).
I then want to create a % increase column based on this Rate Spread.
I have the following code that is giving me a "polars.exceptions.ColumnNotFoundError: Rate Spread"
Attempt #1, yields a error: polars.exceptions.ColumnNotFoundError: Rate Spread
self.yielddiff_lf = self.yielddiff_lf.with_columns(
            (
            (pl.col(f"{numerator} Rate") - pl.col(f"{denominator} Rate"))
                .round(3).alias("Rate Spread")
            ),
            (
                pl.col("Rate Spread").pct_change().alias("Spread % Change")*100)
            )

Attempt #2 yields one column named Spread % Change and I get why:
self.yielddiff_lf = self.yielddiff_lf.with_columns(
            (
            (pl.col(f"{numerator} Rate") - pl.col(f"{denominator} Rate"))
                .round(3).alias("Rate Spread")
            ).pct_change().alias("Spread % Change")*100
            )

how would I create these two columns in the same statement using Polar's LazyFrame?
Attempt #1, yields a error: polars.exceptions.ColumnNotFoundError: Rate Spread
self.yielddiff_lf = self.yielddiff_lf.with_columns(
            (
            (pl.col(f"{numerator} Rate") - pl.col(f"{denominator} Rate"))
                .round(3).alias("Rate Spread")
            ),
            (
                pl.col("Rate Spread").pct_change().alias("Spread % Change")*100)
            )

Attempt #2 yields one column named Spread % Change and I get why, but I am looking to keep both the Rate Spread and % Change column:
self.yielddiff_lf = self.yielddiff_lf.with_columns(
            (
            (pl.col(f"{numerator} Rate") - pl.col(f"{denominator} Rate"))
                .round(3).alias("Rate Spread")
            ).pct_change().alias("Spread % Change")*100
            )


Expression in Polars that refers to earlier alias
